# Change of basis clarification

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

[image]On page 21 of [http://www.mit.edu/~lindrew/18.701.pdf](http://www.mit.edu/%7Elindrew/18.701.pdf), why does $T(B'P^{-1}) = T(B')P^{-1}$?

Comment: Better to write out the whole question here, than to ask people to go offsite to see it.

Comment: Function composition is associative and so matrix multiplication is also associative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrix Multiplication is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Associativity): (AB)C = A(BC) = ABC